# ARGUMENT scope not taking precedence over VARIABLE scope in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, scope, coldfusion-10

As per the [CF documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7fdf.html):

> ARGUMENT scope takes precedence over VARIABLE scope

I tried this code.

```
<cfset fun(25)>
<cffunction name="fun">
  <cfargument name="roll" >
  <cfset roll = 60>
  <cfdump var="#roll#">
</cffunction>
```

I expect the output to be `25`, but its `60`. I cannot understand why the ARGUMENT scope
is not taking precedence over VARIABLE scope? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've just updated `arguments.roll` to 60.  If you want a local function variable that's not going to be overwritten by the argument of the same name, assign it to the `local` scope:

```
<cfset local.roll = 60>
<cfdump var="#roll#">  // 25, as arguments scope takes precedence
<cfdump var="#local.roll#"> // 60
<cfdump var="#arguments#">  // 25
```

Comment: ohh Yes I got. One more thing `<cfset local.roll = 60>` does not throws any error but `<cfset var roll = 60>` throws error. Why?

Comment: that's because you're now creating a variable of the same name as the arguments one; CF can't handle that, which is why you've got to use the `local` scope (or assign it into a structure: `<cfset var myVars.roll = 60>`

Answer (score 5):

It's doing *exactly* what you are expecting it to do (and as per the docs you link to).

You've not qualified your `roll` variable in your `<cfset>`, so the *arguments* scope has taken precedence over the *variables* scope. Just like you wanted.

IE: it's resolve the unscoped reference to `roll` to be `arguments.roll`, not `variables.roll`.

Answer (score 0):

Just you set the roll value as variables.roll

```
<cfset fun(25)>
<cffunction name="fun">
  <cfargument name="roll" >
  <cfset variables.roll = 60>
  <cfdump var="#roll#" /><cfabort />
</cffunction>
```

now the ARGUMENT scope takes precedence over the VARIABLE scope.